# MVEL2 Handle a try/catch block

Tags: mvel

I need to handle a `try catch` block in a `mvel` compiled expression called from `Java`, something like this

```
try {
  func1()
} catch (Exception e) {
 ...do something
}
func2()
```

From my understandings of http://mvel.documentnode.com/ it's not possible. Am I correct?
Any idea to achieve this *inside* the expression? Sadly I can't split the expression to handle the exception in `Java` or modify functions.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

yes u are right we cannot write try/catch block in mvel instead we can use ternary.